# How to save the data in array before showing

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting

How to store the index and value in array before showing them?
It stores the result in a list, sort the list based on the values and show the result index of values before sorting (the original index) and the values like as follow before sorting:

```
0  0.235
1  0.985
2  0.342
3  0.548
4  0.754
```

After sorting:

```
1  0.985
4  0.754
3  0.548
2  0.342
0  0.235
```

---

I mean after getting sorted values(above format): how can I save them into an array instead of showing?

```
                    var results = new List<float>(1143600);
                    for (int z = 0; z < 1143600; z++)
                    {
                        results.Add(dotproduct(userseq, z));
                    }
                    var sb1 = new StringBuilder();
                    foreach (var resultwithindex in results.Select((r, index) => new { result = r, Index = index }).OrderByDescending(r => r.result).Take(n))
                    {
                        sb1.AppendFormat("{0}: {1}", resultwithindex.Index, resultwithindex.result);
                        sb1.AppendLine();
                    }
                    MessageBox.Show(sb1.ToString());
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure about your question but maybe this is want you want:

```
var array = results.Select((r, index) => new { result = r, Index = index })
                   .OrderByDescending(r => r.result)
                   .Take(n)
                   .ToArray();
```

Comment: Thank you @FlatEric.I am beginner. May you tell e were I must put this line of code and explain how to save the index and result in array?

Comment: And I think it must be a list. Am I right? @
Flat Eric

Comment: Index and value are contained in the anonymous class you created with the select-statement. You can access them with "var idx = array[i].Index;" and "var value = array[i].result;". If you want a list instead of an array just use .ToList().

Comment: If I want to compare each index with an on dimensional array to replace the value of array instead of index , what should i do?  please specify your answer by comment on the script @FlatEric .(i mean read that value and put it instead of current index)

Comment: You cannot replace a value of one of these array elements (you get a compiler error that says that it is read-only) but you can create a new array and fill it in a foreach loop iterating over your existing array